# What is an efficient way to bulk copy data from a CLOB column to a VARCHAR2 column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have a table TEST that has 41 million+ records in it.

I have two main columns in this table that I am interested in:

- MESSAGE of type CLOB
- MESSAGE_C of type VARCHAR2(2048)

The table Test is range partitioned using a partition column named PART_DATE where one partition has data for one day.

I tried using the below to get the job done:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD MESSAGE_C VARCHAR2(2048);
UPDATE TEST SET MESSAGE_C = MESSAGE;
COMMIT;
ALTER TABLE TEST DROP COLUMN MESSAGE;
ALTER TABLE TEST RENAME COLUMN MESSAGE_C TO MESSAGE;
```

But I got stuck on step 2 for around 4 hours. Our DBA said, these was a blocking due to full table scans.

Can someone please tell me:

1. What would be a better/more efficient way to get this done?
2. Would using the PART_DATE field in the where clause of the update query help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using an INSERT INTO SELECT to create the new table on the fly with a new name, then add the indexes after creating the table, drop the old table, and rename the new table to the old name.

It's a DML operation, so it will be significantly faster, and also isn't slowed down by server logging settings.

I've used this approach to alter tables with 500 million records a bit recently.

Comment: thanks for your input. This seems to work well for me. &#128077;

Comment: awesome to hear that